# Assign a string but get back an object -the browser at play?

Tags: javascript, dom

Given this tag:

```
<p id="myp">foo para
```

I know you're not supposed to, but if I assign a string to the `style` property of the corresponding DOM object, I can change its style:

```
let p = document.getElementById('myp');
p.style = 'color: red'; //assign a string
```

`p.style` should now point to a string, I suppose. But if I then ask for the style property, I get an object rather than a string:

```
console.log(p.style); //get back an object
```

Normally in JavaScript if I assign a string to a variable or object property, I expect the value to still be a string when I ask for that value. So is the browser jumping in to change this, or is there a JavaScript mechanism at play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById` returns an [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), and if you look at it's prototype [image]

we see that `style` is not a "normal" property, but actually a `getter` and [`setter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).

Obviously this is a super simplified example, but essentially it would be implemented something like:

```js
  let element = {
        color: 'red',
        get style() {
            return { color: this.color }
        },
        set style(s) {
            this.color = s.split(': ')[1]
        }
    }

element.style = 'color: blue';
console.log(element.style);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you debug `HTMLElement.prototype` in the console, you can see that `style` is an accessor property. When you assign a value to it, instead of just overwriting the property in question it executes a setter method, which can override the value you passed. This is without a doubt in place to ensure that the `style` property is always an object (namely an instance of `CSSStyleDeclaration`), since a lot of things rely on that.

To overwrite the `style` *attribute* of the element, you can safely use `p.setAttribute('style', 'color: red');`

Answer (score 1):

Style of the p element is an object containing all of its styles, you need to select which style you want.

UPDATE: You can get your string back from the `cssText` also in the snippet.

`p.style = 'color: red';`  I believe this line is taken as:

```
p.style.color: 'red';
```

```js
let p = document.getElementById('myp');
p.style = 'color: red';
console.log(p.style.color);

console.log(p.style.cssText);
```

```html
<p id="myp">foo para<p>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to mozilla documentation

> The HTMLElement.style property is used to get as well as set the
>   inline style of an element. While getting, it returns a
>   [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) object that contains a list of all styles
>   properties for that element with values assigned for the attributes
>   that are defined in the element's inline style attribute.

See: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style